# I want all table rows to be same height and columns to be scrollable (if needed)

Tags: html, css, arrays, overflow

I have written a code that should make all rows the same height and if there is more info in a column than fits, a scrollbar should appear. At the moment though some rows come out bigger and no scroll bars appear.

```
var table = '<table>';
                for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    var item = jsonData\[i\];
                    table += '<tr>';
                    table += '<td align="left" class="align-middle" height="65px">'
                        +item.firstName+'</td>';
                    table += '<td class="align-middle" height="65px" overflow-y="auto">'
                        +item.agegroup+'</td>';
                    table += '<td class="align-middle" height="65px" overflow-y="auto">'
                        +item.subject+'</td>';
                    table += '<td class="align-middle" height="65px" overflow-y="auto">'
                        +item.location+'</td>';
                    table += '</tr>';
                }
                table += '</table>';
                document.getElementById("fulltable").innerHTML = table;
```

Comment: Try either height="65" or style="height:65px". Or even more clean is to define the height in a class and apply that class to your td's

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div inside `<td>` and add height and overflow: auto; on that div

```css
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
table tr td .scroll{
  height:65px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" class="align-middle"><div class="scroll">Lorem Ipsum</div></td>
    <td class="align-middle"><div class="scroll">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div></td>
    <td class="align-middle"><div class="scroll">Lorem Ipsum</div></td>
    <td class="align-middle"><div class="scroll">Lorem Ipsum</div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" class="align-middle"><div class="scroll">Lorem Ipsum</div></td>
    <td class="align-middle"><div class="scroll">Industry Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting</div></td>
    <td class="align-middle"><div class="scroll">Lorem Ipsum</div></td>
    <td class="align-middle"><div class="scroll">Lorem Ipsum</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can I also write like this:
<div height="65px" overflow-y="auto">, or this still remains in <td> part?

Comment: Put style in css file and modify your code like 
`table += '<td align="left" class="align-middle" height="65px"><div class="scroll">'+item.firstName+'</div></td>';`